# "An Fahrt aufnehmen" oder "Fahrt aufnehmen"

Tags: difference

> Vor dem Hintergrund einer robusten Weltkonjunktur konnte auch die Wirtschaft in Deutschland Fahrt aufnehmen,...
>
> Auch in Deutschland wird die Biogasbranche wieder an Fahrt aufnehmen,...

Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken?
Oder ist es ähnlich wie bei "Vertrauen verlieren/gewinnen" und "an Vertrauen verlieren/gewinnen"?

Comment: Beides bedeutet genau dasselbe.

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach ist der zweite Ausdruck falsch. Der richtige Ausdruck lautet "Fahrt aufnehmen", ein Synonym ist "an Fahrt gewinnen". Aber die Kombination "an Fahrt aufnehmen" ist falsch.

Comment: @IQV : Wie begründest Du, dass "an Fahrt aufnehmen" falsch ist? Ich kann auf duden.de weder ein Argument dafür oder dagegen finden. Dass das "an" hier überflüssig ist, sehe ich ein, aber warum ist es falsch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fahrt aufnehmen

ist auf jeden Fall ein korrekter Ausdruck, der sich auf [diese Bedeutung von *aufnehmen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufnehmen#Bedeutung2) bezieht. *Fahrt* ist in diesem Zusammenhang äquivalent zu [Geschwindigkeit des Fahrens](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fahrt#Bedeutung1b).

Die Präposition *an* wird in folgenden Beispielen, manchmal wahlfrei, verwendet:

> an Fahrt gewinnen, an Größe zunehmen, an Wert verlieren, ...

Dies ist in den entsprechenden Artikeln der Verben im Duden vermerkt (Beispiel [*zunehmen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zunehmen#Bedeutung1b)). 
Im oben verlinkten Artikel von *aufnehmen* ist das nicht der Fall. Zudem, wie IQV in einem Kommentar schreibt, taucht der Ausdruck *an Fahrt aufnehmen* bei [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20Fahrt%20aufnehmen%2C%20Fahrt%20aufnehmen%2C%20an%20Fahrt%20gewinnen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFahrt%20aufnehmen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20Fahrt%20gewinnen%3B%2Cc0) nicht auf. Würde man ihn dennoch verwenden, so müsste *an Fahrt* ein feststehender Begriff sein, was nicht der Fall ist.

Es gibt meines Erachtens keinerlei Hinweise darauf, dass der Ausdruck *"an Fahrt aufnehmen"* korrekt ist, somit stufe ich ihn als falsch ein.

Answer (score 1):

Das »[an](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/an_Praeposition#Bedeutung3)« ist wahlfrei, ändert nichts an der Bedeutung.

Änlich wie »Fahrt aufnehmen«:

> - in Fahrt kommen
> - in Schwung kommen

Beispiele:

> Vor dem Hintergrund einer robusten Weltkonjunktur kam auch die
>   deutsche Wirtschaft in Fahrt / in Schwung.
>
> Auch in Deutschland wird die Biogasbranche wieder in Fahrt / in Schwung kommen.

Comment: Ein [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+Fahrt+aufnehmen%2C+Fahrt+aufnehmen%2C+an+Fahrt+gewinnen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFahrt%20aufnehmen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20Fahrt%20gewinnen%3B%2Cc0) gibt für "an Fahrt aufnehmen" null Treffer aus, für die anderen Ausdrücke hingegen schon einige Ergebnisse.

Comment: @IQV: _»an Fahrt aufnehmen«_ wird selten bis gar nicht verwendet, falsch ist es nicht. Warum meinst du, dass es falsch ist?

Comment: Gegenfrage: Warum meinst du, dass es richtig sei? Es mögen vielleicht drei grammatikalisch richtig aneinander gereihte Wörter sein. Aber wird dadurch der Ausdruck richtig? Ich konnte nirgends einen Nachweis finden, dass der Ausdruck "an Fahrt aufnehmen" existiert. Für mich bedeutet das, dass man den Ausdruck so nicht verwendet, also falsch ist.

Comment: @IQV: Ich meine, dass _»Fahrt aufnehmen«_ im wörtlichen Sinne _»schneller werden«_ bedeutet und nicht _»anfahren«_. Diejenigen, die meinen, _»an Fahrt aufnehmen«_ sei falsch, mögen bei _»Fahrt aufnehmen«_ von _»anfahren«_ ausgehen.

Comment: @Pollitzer Ich verstehe nicht, warum die Bedeutung *"schneller werden"* das *an* rechtfertigt. Für mich gibt es keine Regel, auf die es sich stützt, und keinerlei Vorkommen in deutscher Literatur. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass das korrekt ist, ist somit sehr gering.

Comment: @RoyPJ: aufnehmen = vom Boden aufheben und obendrauf setzen. Ob du jetzt _»Fahrt«_ draufsetzt oder _»an Fahrt«_, das ist egal.

Comment: Das ist nicht die verwendete Bedeutung hier, sondern diese: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufnehmen#Bedeutung2
Somit kann man *Fahrt* im Sinne von *Geschwindigkeit* aufnehmen. Aber um *an Fahrt* aufzunehmen müsste *an Fahrt* ja ein feststehender Begriff sein.