# Translating a sentence with "an Fahrt"

Tags: german-to-english, grammar-identification

> Obwohl aufgrund der stetig **an Fahrt** aufnehmenden Erderwärmung an allen Küsten dieser Erde die Wasserspiegel steigen, nehmen die verfügbaren Süßwasservorräte rasant ab.

I am having difficulty translating the above sentence due to the "an Fahrt" part. Could someone guide me on how to do it?

When I check in reverso, it tells me that *an Fahrt* means the same as the English noun momentum, but to my understanding, *an Fahrt* acts like an adverb in the above.

So does the said English translation of "momentum" not work here? How do I translate it then?

Comment: In German already discussed here. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41582/an-fahrt-aufnehmen-oder-fahrt-aufnehmen

Answer (score 2):

*Stetig [an] Fahrt aufnehmend* simply translates to

> steadily accelerating

As stated in the linked question and its answers, *an* can at least be safely omitted.

*Gaining momentum* would be an alternative, if you want to keep the construct involving a noun.